# Which of the ordered field axioms fail for the irrational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

I think that the following fail:

1. There exists an irrational number denoted $0$ such that $a+0=a$ for all irrational numbers $a$, because there is no such irrational number.
2. For all irrational numbers $a$, there exists a unique irrational number $a\cdot b$ because take for example a number $\sqrt2$ and another irrational number $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$. If I multiply these I get $1$, except $1$ is not an irrational number.
3. There exists an irrational number denoted $1$ such that $a\cdot 1=a$ for all irrational numbers a because there is no such irrational number.
4. There is a subset $P$ of $I$ referred to as the positive irrational numbers, such that for all irrational numbers $a$, exactly one of the following holds: $a$ is in $P$, $a=0$, or $-a$ is in $P$. This fails because $a$ cannot be $0$ since $0$ is not an irrational number.

Firstly, am I correct about these properties failing, and secondly, did I miss any other axioms that fail as well?

Comment: The irrational numbers are closed under neither addition nor multiplication, thus you don't even have the binary operations $X\times X\rightarrow X$ to form a field.

Comment: Are you assuming that $+$ and $\cdot$ are the usual sum and multiplication with real numbers?

Comment: @mfl yes, they are the usual addition and multiplication

Comment: Once you see that you don't even have well-defined operations (as J. David Taylor pointed out), lots of things crumble, for example the associative law, $(a+b)+c=a+(b+c)$. If $a=-b=\sqrt2$ and $c=\pi$ then the left side is undefined (because $a+b=0$ isn't in your set) but the right side is defined and equal to $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

$$ (1 + \pi) - \pi = 1 \in \mathbb{Q}$$